# Object Values as Another Object's Keys

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how can I take an object's values:

```
var fieldsObject = ['contentA', 'contentB', 'contentC', 'contentD'];
```

and plug them in as keys of another object?

```
result[contentA][contentB][contentC][contentD]
```

My inclination is to loop, but not I'm not seeing how to construct this.

Comment: can u give more details on what u trying to accomplish

Comment: what do you expect for it's value ?
do u want something like result[contentA]=value1, result[contentB]=value2 or something like result[contentA][contentB].... = some_value.     for 1st case do like,
`
 var result={}  for(key in fieldObject){
    result[key] = value // value 1,2,...
}
`

Comment: Someone posted an answer, now it's gone. However, it works for what I'm doing. For the record, here's my 'accepted answer':

`function accessObject(mainObject, fieldsObjects) { 
  var access = mainObject;
  while (fieldsObjects.length > 0) { 
    var key = fieldsObjects.shift(); 
    if (access[key] !== undefined) { 
      access = access[key]; 
    } else { 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
  return access; 
}`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nakib. What worked for me is posted above.